# Javascript spritesheet score display

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am creating a game using JavaScript and the canvas API. I would like to implement a score at the top of the canvas which is constructed from a set of sprites on a sprite sheet. I have a sprite sheet containing images of numbers from 0 - 9. I want to know how I would go about displaying the player's current score to the canvas from the set of images. This would be including digits beyond 9(which I think confuses me most). Could you please annotate every line of code here just so I can fully understand.Thank you to everyone who replies.

Comment: You should probably reword this question, as it will get quickly voted down.  You are basically asking people to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick simple solution using object property names to lookup the image details for each character you want to draw.

Convert the score to a string and then find the character code for each character in the string. Use the character code to look up the image details and then draw the image.

```
var numbers = {  // for each character create a property that has its ASCII code
    c48:{
        image:imgForZero,  // the image for the character zero
        offx:0,  // x offset if needed
        offy:0,  // y offset if needed
        widthToNext: 10,  // distance to the next character so you can have
                          // variable spacing 
    },
    c49: ...   // do the same for each character you want to display
               // you can find the codes here     
               // http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp
    },
    c50: ...
    .. and so on
}
var chars = score.toString(); // turn score to a string
var x = 10,y = 20;  // the top left of the score position
for(var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){ // for each character
    var charCode = chars.charCodeAt(i); // get the character code
    var charData = numbers["c"+charCode];  // get the image details
    if(charData !== undefined){  // make sure it is in the data
        // draw the image with the offset
        ctx.drawImage(charData.image, x + charData.offx, y + charData.offy);
        // move to the next character position
        x += charData.widthToNext; // 
    }
}
// All done
```

I answers to try and stop this getting a negative rating as it is a good question and shows  how to use bracket notation to do lookups rather than array.find

Comment: Thank you very much, and thank you for annotating the code. This was literally my first post so forgive me if it was slightly confusing... or stupid for that matter.

Comment: Glad I could help, and not at all a stupid question, everyone that writes a game has to address this same problem. Don't worry about the negative points on the question, it was just the way you worded it.